# Formula to sum the 5 cells and classify it based on the result

Tags: excel-formula

I am a beginner to the Excel formula Please help to build the excel formula to sum the values in the rows (Z13:AC13) and from the result classify the value based on the below Classifications.

```
Unlikely: >=4<6
Possible: >=6<9
Likely: >=9<12
Certain: >=12<=16
```

I tried the below code but it is not working:

```
=IF(OR(SUM(Z13:AC13)>=4,SUM(Z13:AC13)<6),"Unlikely"),IF(OR(SUM(Z13:AC13)>=6,SUM(Z13:AC13)<9),"Possible"),IF(OR(SUM(Z13:AC13)>=9,SUM(Z13:AC13)<12),"Likely"),IF(OR(SUM(Z13:AC13)>=12,SUM(Z13:AC13)<=16),"Certain")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(SUM(Z13:AC13),{4,6,9,12}),"Unlikely","Possible","Likely","Certain")
```

Answer (score 0):

Scott's answer is better, but if you'd rather have a more complicated formula that uses fewer Excel concepts, this worked for me:

`=IF(AND(total>=4,total<6),"unlikely",IF(AND(total>=6,total<9),"possible",IF(AND(total>=9,total<12),"likely",IF(AND(total>=12,total<=16),"certain","---"))))`

"---" is there in case the total is ever >16 by accident.

I gave the cell containing the sum the range name `total` to make the formula a little easier to read. If you don't like that, substitute `SUM(Z13:AC13)` for `total`.

I think the problem with your formula is the parenthesis after (for instance), the word "unlikely". It messes up the nesting. You don't want

```
IF(OR(SUM(Z13:AC13)>=4,SUM(Z13:AC13)<6),"Unlikely"),IF(OR...
```

you just want

```
IF(OR(SUM(Z13:AC13)>=4,SUM(Z13:AC13)<6),"Unlikely",IF(OR...
```

Simpler example showing the substitution of a whole second IF statement for `condition-if-false`:

```
=IF(criterion,condition-if-true,condition-if-false)
=IF(criterion,condition-if-true,IF(criterion,condition-if-true,condition-if-false))
```

Try it for practice:

Cell A1: blank cell for data

Cell B1: enter the formula `=IF(A1="a","a",IF(A1="b","b","neither"))`

Then enter a, b, or c into A1 to see what happens in B1.

A good tip is if you're having trouble with a formula, abandon your real data for a minute and make a dummy example that's as simple as possible. Get that to work, and then substitute your real conditions one step at a time.

Comment: This too worked, Thanks a lot for your time and effort